# Kак создать oбъект под каждый символ? Количество определяет пользователь

Tags: c#

Kак создать `new RomanExpression` под каждый символ?

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
List<RomanExpression> number = new List<RomanExpression>();
//foreach (char item in str) 
//number.Add(new RomanExpression(item.ToString()));

var exp = new AddExpression(new AddExpression(new RomanExpression("I"),
          new RomanExpression("X")), new AddExpression(new RomanExpression("V"), 
          new RomanExpression("C")));
```

Comment: Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: Римские цифры в int, через паттерн interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
List<RomanExpression> number = new List<RomanExpression>();
String[] substrings = str.Split();
foreach (var item in substrings)
    number.Add(new RomanExpression(item.ToString()));
```